# blender 2.83: find imported GLB mesh

Tags: import, gltf

In 2.82, I was able to import and find the imported GLB mesh by

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=input_filename)
imported = bpy.context.selected_objects
```

However, in 2.83, it does not seem to auto-select as active object after it finishes import.
How am I supposed to find the imported things in 2.83 programmatically?

Comment: If the other importers auto-select the result, this could be considered an issue in the glTF importer, possibly.  You might want to file it here:  https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues